# Android strategic decision on data persistence

Tags: java, android

I dont know where to ask about this, I cannot find strategic information, "whole picture" information regarding android app architecture, so please bear with me on this one. I tried programmers.stackexchange, but there is almost no activity there.

Here is my question:

I have an android app in which users have sets of items, and each item has about 10 properties.

What I do at the moment:

- items are stored in the server database
- when the user logs in, I get all the items (say 37) via the API and put them in a LinkedHashSet< UserItem > (UserItem is a POJO with setters and getters)
- then I get the 37 items from the set and put them in the local SQLite database
- when the user opens "My Items" screen in the app, i get the 37 items from the local SQLite DB

I was thinking, is this a good practice? Could I circumvent Step 3(storing items in the local database), but instead maintain the life of that LinkedHashSet object and get the items directly from there. If Im right with this suggestion, how do I do that?

Comment: that depends on the constraints. Of course you could keep it in ram. You should ask yourself: do I need to cache those data?

Comment: I dont know anything about caching at the moment, I've left learning this for a later stage. I need this object to be accessible during the lyfecicle of the app until the user logs out (they may not want to log out for days or even weeks)

Comment: there are constraints, yes - item_category and item_subcategory are foreign keys pointing to a table in the sqlite db

Comment: that's not a project constraints. A constraint could be: User has to access the application also if the network is not available. What If  the application crashes but the data you retrieved are still valid? You want to make another http call to retrieve it? You should take in account those kind of considerations.

Comment: so its better to do what I do at the moment?

Comment: That's in a way touching the [Single Source of Truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth) idea. Every data source can potentially be out of sync with other sources and that results in problems. Adding a local database adds complexity but it allows your app to become independent of restarts and network instability. That's your decision. A caching layer is usually placed in between your memory state and the external database so data flows from external > cache > memory. You could update memory and cache in parallel directly from external but that results in even more complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, in my own experience, I'd avoid the second database storage. Introducing 2 databases, one for loading and one to storing introduces a new potential point of failure, because additionally on having synchronized your data in memory, you have to synchronize both databases at some point, and this implies an additional process you have to implement, which might be expensive in performance.

What's more: Suppose you have synchronized your `LinkedHashSet` with your local SQLite DB but it's not synchronized with your server's DB, and for some reason Android decides terminating your app: you have your `LinkedHashSet` in memory and oops... your changes in memory are lost. Now you restart your app, which DB has the most updated data? Ok, you could store a `last_change` timestamp value but what I'm trying to make see it's not worth it. At least not two of the same kind.

What I'd do is one of those:

- Just use the central server Database. To synchronize, while your app is alive, periodically (in a reasonable amount of time) open a new `Thread` or `AsyncTask` which would open a `Socket` to your central database and synchronize your data (a similar behavior to the `Saving as draft...` mechanism). Your app may crash, but if you synchronize your data periodically, the losses won't be that catastrophic as you wouldn't because you'll have a reasonably recent backup. In favour of this approach is the fact that this way you'll always have your data *almost* up-to-date. The disadvantage is that you'll have to set up a "stronger" database server (I mean in hardware performance) as if you plan to have much users, the requests to your DB will be considerably more frequent now (for writing, overall). Another disatvantage is the connectivity subject. It might happen that on certain point you cannot connect to your database due to connectivity issues, but that would just mean you have to handle this process by `catch`ing the corresponding `Exception`s.
- If you don't like the first approach, there's another idea: You use a POJO, that means that it can be converted into a JSON, thus you can save it into `SharedPreferences`. This could be your secondary database, and together with the idea of periodically synchronize, you could simply save it into your `SharedPreferences` and use it as storage. Once in a time simply synchronize those preferences with your central database (for example, each time you start your app), and the main advantage is that this is a quite efficient operation (so you could invoke it probably more often than the database synchronization approach), and this way you would have some kind of *replication* system.

Comment: first approch: where does this asynctask store the newly syncronozed data?

Comment: secodn approach - Im already using this approach for the basic user data but I think its unthinkable to store user's 100 items with their 10 properties each in sharedprefs

Comment: the way Im syncronizing data now is, whenever a user deletes or adds a new item, the local db is deleted and downloaded a new from the server. also, the db is deleted at user log out, so when they log in I download everything again

Comment: and what do I do in situations like search results (that do not need to be stored at all) how do I dynamically load the server json in the list view with the results?

Comment: For the first approach: I mean storing your `LinkedHashSet` into your server's database, so basically establishing a connection to your remote server and save there your data within your `LinkedHashSet` every short amount of time. For the second approach: If you have 100 items with 10 properties each, indeed it might not be a good idea... I think the way that you're synchronizing right now is a bit overworked; you don't need to delete the whole DB, simply update the changed data. Regarding to the search, you mean you want to allow searching over your items within a `ListView`?

Comment: About the search - the user is going to search the whole database for other users' items. I create a querty to the server and get an unknown quantity of items and their properties. How do I display those in a ListView (the search results set) without first storing them to a local db. Do I just create a LinkedHashSet, send it to the adapter and then get rid of it? If its possible, seems fine to me

Comment: Storing that within one DB to other seems a redundant step, I'd avoid that, indeed. I'd simply do what you propose, extract the data and show it within a `ListView`. This is reasonably easily doable by using a `CursorAdapter`. You'd simply extend that class if you need to manage it your way (you probably should, as you're not using standard data but a `Class` that represent 10 properties). I've followed this reference and it worked for me, should do exactly what you want: http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/

Comment: I will award my bounty in 19 hours :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on Android keeping your app instance active; the OS can and will terminate your process, sometimes even giving it some time to clean up.

Comment: so I should store everything in the local sqlite? how about stuff that I do not want to store in the database, like Search results.. how can I dynamically load them from the server json straight into the list adapter?